# Nested For loops, X-mas tree in C

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, tree, nested

So I have the task of creating a Christmas tree in C, I know this has been done to death but there are some conditions that have to be meet that leave me beyond confused, I don't even know where to start.

So we ask the user for the number of levels(how many lines in the layer) and then the number of layers.

Now, each line after the first in each layer will add 2 " *  " one to each side of the first( which is just a line with one " * ".) And we do this until the number of levels in the layer is meet, then the next layer is started. When I new layer is started we subtract 4( 2" * " from each side, of the last level in the previous layer, and then repeat the process of adding 1 " * " to each side until the number of levels is meet( the number of levels is decided upon in the beginning and is constant.)

Finally the last part is finishing off the tree of the tree with a width 3, height 4 trunk made of " # ". I have no idea how I'm supposed to be setting up these loops, I'll post what I've done so far( not much I'm unsure how to proceed)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){


int levels;
int levelcount;
int layers;
int i;
int j;

    printf(" How many levels should this tree have?\n");
    scanf("%d\n", levels);

    printf(" How many layers should this tree have?\n");
    scanf("%d\n");

for (level = 0;level <= levelcount ; levelcount++){


}








return 0;

}
```

for example a sample out put with 2 layers of 3 levels would be

```
     *
    ***
   *****
     *
    ***
   *****
    ###
    ###
    ###
    ###
```

---

Below is some updated code for where i'm at now

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){


int level;
int levelcount;
int layercount;
int layer;
int star;
int starcount;
int space;
int spacecount;
int spacenumber;

    printf("How many levels should this tree have?\n");
    scanf("%d\n", &level);

    printf(" How many layers should this tree have?\n");
    scanf("%d\n", &layer);

for (layer = 0;layer <= layercount ; layercount++){


                star= 2*level - 1;
                space= levelcount + level - star;

            for (spacecount =0; spacecount <=spacenumber; spacecount++)
                printf(" ");

            for (starcount= 0; star < starcount; starcount++)
                printf("%c" , '*');

            for (levelcount=1; levelcount=1;levelcout++)







}







return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you clearify the substraction part? What should be a layer and what's a level? Maybe you could give an example how the tree should look like.

Comment: The level refers to the number of line before the subtraction, which starts the next layer. So it'd be " * " and then we add 2 so it's another start on each side of the previous line " * * * " and we continue to add 2 stars on each side until the number of lines(or levels) is meet. The If the user has specified more layers. We begin the next layer by subtraction 4 total " * " from the last line of the 1st layer( 2 " * " from each side. and then continue on again, until the nemer of layers is meet.

Comment: layers are the number of lines in a layer, and layers refere to the number of times, the lines will be printed. So a layer of 4 with 3 lines, will have 3 lines printed 4 times, but we are to add 2 stars(  *  )  to each line in the layer until the beginning of the next layer, where we will initially subtract 4 stars, and then add 1 to each side on the next line, until the layer is repeated, and this happens until the for loop for layers is meet.

Comment: level 1( *) level 2( ***) level 3 ( *****) level 4 ( *******) now we start the next layer so the first line has 4 stars removed( 2 from each side. (layer 2, level 1( ***) layer 2 , level 2, ( *****) and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is the result you want to see:

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
        ###
        ###
```

This would be 2 levels of 6 layers. 
So you're first idea to use a for-loop over the levels should be good:

```
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
```

This is the first level of the tree. 
To create the layer of this level, we'd need another, nested for-loop:

```
 for (level = 0;level <= levelcount ; levelcount++){
    for (layer=0; layer <= layers; layer++) {
       do_something
    }
 }
```

So what about the `do_something`? Well here is the tricky part, you have to calculate the number of stars to be printed in this line.
For this, let's add the level/layer/# of stars information to the tree:

```
         *            
        ***           1/1/3
       *****          1/2/5
      *******         1/3/7
     *********        1/4/9
       *****          2/1/5
      *******         2/2/7
     *********        2/3/9
    ***********       2/4/11
```

As for every line, two stars are added to the line we can infer that the number of start must be somthing with two times the number of lines. So for the lines my first guess would be `stars = x + [(layer - 1) * 2]`. This can easily be approved by setting x to the number of stars at the top of every layer. So for second layer `x = 5` then 2nd line of this is `5 + [(2 - 1) * 2] = 7` or for 4th line in first layer `3 + [(4 - 1) * 2] = 9`.
To get this `x` we need to know the number of stars in the last layer of the last level and substract 4. We could use some calculation for this as well, but let's make life easy and just remeber the number of stars we used:

```
 int x = 3;
 for (level = 0;level <= levelcount ; levelcount++){
    for (layer=0; layer <= layers; layer++) {
       print_num_of_stars(x + ((layer - 1) * 2)
    }
    x = x + ((layers - 1) * 2) - 4
 }
```

Now the last problem you have to solve is filling all the lines with the needed amount of spaces in print_num_of_stars, but this is just another for-loop too.

Hope this helped, please forgive if I messed up layers and levels sometimes.

Comment: So I've set up al my loops for the tree minus the one where we subtract 4 stars for the first line of the next layer. Also I'm having a problem where my program doesnt progress to the next printf after inputing the first value.